# order by JSON data type SQLAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a Postgres table that has a JSON type column that has a bunch of JSON objects in it. I want to query the records of a table and order the results by key value stored in a JSON field.

```
row1 {'2011': 600, '2012': 100, '2014': 200}
row2 {'2011': 700, '2012': 100, '2014': 200}
row3 {'2011': 500, '2012': 100, '2014': 200}
```

How can I make a request like this:

```
Table.query.order_by(Table.data['2011']).all()
```

Whith result:

```
500
600
700
```

I have tried the queries:

```
Table.query.order_by(Table.data.cast(JSON)['2011']).all()
Table.query.order_by(Table.data(JSON)['2011']).all()
```

But I always get various errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by extracting the value as text and then casting to an integer.  Precisely how to do this depends on the column type in the database and in the model.

If the column type in the database is JSON, and the column type in the model is SQLAlchemy's generic [JSON](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.JSON) type, you need to cast the value to a text type, and then to an numeric type.

```py
# Get these from the db namespace if using Flask-SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import cast, Integer, String
...
Table.query.order_by(cast(cast(tbl.c.data['2011'], String), sa.Integer)).all()
```

If the column in the database is JSON, and the column type in the model is the [JSON](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSON) type from SQLAlchemy's PostgresSQL dialect, you can use the column's `astext` attribute instead of casting to a text type. (You can change the column type from generic JSON to Postgres JSON in the model with having to migrate).

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSON
...
Table.query.order_by(cast(Table.data['2011'].astext, Integer)).all()
```

If the column type in the database is JSONB and the column type in the model is [JSONB](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB), you can use the value directly:

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB
...
Table.query.order_by(Table.data['2011']).all()
```

Comment: I used the first option which showed me an error: `AttributeError: Neither 'BinaryExpression' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'astext'`

Comment: db.Column(db.JSON)

Comment: I've edited the answer to handle the generic JSON type too.

Comment: GREAT! This code worked: `Table.query.order_by(cast(cast(tbl.c.data['2011'], String), Integer)).all()` Thank you very much!